# subversion tool that also includes the include files of a program when showing changes

Tags: c, svn

We have subversion to help us manage our c files (and tortoise svn as front end).

When I want to know the changes in a c module, I (of course) only get the changes in the "body" of the program, not the changes in the include files.

So I wrote a small simple programm finding out all include files of a c module, checking the last subversion change date for each include file and writing the result in an output file.

This way  I get a full impression of what has changed recently in the whole module.

But the program is very simple and I would like to know, if there is a solution out there that handles this "full view" of a c module in good way.

As I work on multiple independent change requests at one time in one subversion working folder, it does not help just looking at the result of "check for modifications".

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Simply add your include files, as well as the C files, to the version control? That you have to view the h and c files separately in some diff viewer doesn't seem like a huge problem to me.

Comment: If you have around 80 include files and you want to know where there has only been recent changes it is rather tiresome.

Comment: I still don't understand the problem. Surely your SVN client has a log over all commits, sorted by date? Simply check it to see which files that were recently changed, no matter if they are h files or c files?

Comment: But in this overall log there are the commits for all include files of all modules in my working folder, not just for the one module I want. And there I cannot say: "Just show me all commits related to this module and the include files of this module".

Comment: Ah okay now I understand the problem. When you pick show log for an individual c file, you want to see the change log for all included header files as well (the whole "translation unit"). Makes sense.

Comment: Exactly, thanks to make that clear.

Answer (score 1):

Some handwork (onetime) required, but it *can* work

Using (file-level type for all files in every "project" /reqiure SVN 1.6+/) create virtual (or real) folders, which will include all files for each project. After it `svn log` inside such folder in WC will show only related to project-files changes